# Serialising Arrays containing object to Avro in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, serialization, avro

I'm currently trying to generate an AvroValue composed by an AvroRecord which is composed by different AvroValues, AvroRecords, AvroArrays and AvroArrays containing AvroRecords.

After that, the whole Avro object is encoded resulting in to an byte array, which will be sent later to the server.

I could design a solution for most of them, however, the creation of AvroArrays containing AvroRecords is not working as expected.

**-  While encoding an object of 6 variables I receive the next byte array. [2, 2, 6, 117, 114, 108, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],**

**- I receive the next one for the same object but in this case into the AvroArray. [2, 2]** Which make no sense.

This is complicated stuff to explain by me, so I'm going to sow both codes.

**Finally, just to mention that I'm pretty sure that the incorrect code is in the method "avroNullableArrayValue" or in the way It's being called and used.**

**AvroRecord Example:** (Working)

```
let jsonSchemaResult = "  {\r\n  \"namespace\": \"x\",\r\n  \"doc\": \"1\",\r\n  \"type\": \"record\",\r\n  \"name\": \"event\",\r\n  \"fields\": [\r\n    {\"name\": \"event_httppageload\",  \"type\": [\"null\", {\r\n       \"type\": \"record\",\r\n       \"name\": \"EventHttppageloadRecord\",\r\n       \"fields\": [\r\n          {\"name\": \"url\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"]},\r\n          {\"name\": \"setup_time\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"int\"]},\r\n          {\"name\": \"duration\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"int\"]},\r\n          {\"name\": \"data_downloaded\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"int\"]},\r\n          {\"name\": \"is_error\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"boolean\"]},\r\n          {\"name\": \"error_code\", \"type\": [\"null\", {\"type\": \"enum\", \"name\": \"HttpErrorCodeEnum\", \"symbols\" : [\"NO_ERROR\", \"FILE_NOT_FOUND\", \"NETWORK_ERROR\", \"NETWORK_TIMEOUT\",\"INTERNAL_ERROR\"]}]}\r\n       ]\r\n       \r\n    }]}]}"

 let schema = Schema(jsonSchemaResult)
 let avroValue: AvroValue
//Please ignore the variable "result", it is never used
 avroValue = result.toAvro()
 let encodedBytes = avroValue.encode(schema!)

extension ResultObject : AvroValueConvertible {
    public func toAvro() -> AvroValue {
        let object1: DCUrlResult = DCUrlResult.init(url: "url", label: "label", loadTime: 111, pingTime: 222, pageSize: 333, error: true)

        let returnThink = AvroValue.avroRecordValue([
            "event_httppageload" : avroNullableRecordValue(v: object1, converter: {
                let newAvro = AvroValue.avroRecordValue([
                    "url" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                    "setup_time" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                    "duration" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                    "data_downloaded" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                    "is_error" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                    "error_code" : $0.url.toAvroString()
                ])
                return newAvro
            })
        ])
    }
}

 public func avroNullableRecordValue<T>(v: T?, converter: (T) -> AvroValue) -> AvroValue{
     if(v == nil) {
         let box = Box(AvroValue.avroNullValue)
         return .avroUnionValue(0, box)
     } else {
         let pend2 = converter(v!)
         let box = Box(pend2)
         return .avroUnionValue(1, box)
     }
 }

extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    public func toAvroString() -> AvroValue {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            let box = Box(AvroValue.avroNullValue)
            return .avroUnionValue(0, box)
        case .some(let v):
            let box = Box(v.toAvro())
            return .avroUnionValue(1, box)
        }
    }
}
extension Optional where Wrapped == Int32 {
    public func toAvro() -> AvroValue {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            let box = Box(AvroValue.avroNullValue)
            return .avroUnionValue(0, box)
        case .some(let v):
            let box = Box(v.toAvro())
            return .avroUnionValue(1, box)
        }
    }
}
extension Optional where Wrapped == Bool {
    public func toAvro() -> AvroValue {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            let box = Box(AvroValue.avroNullValue)
            return .avroUnionValue(0, box)
        case .some(let v):
            let box = Box(v.toAvro())
            return .avroUnionValue(1, box)
        }
    }
}
```

**AvroArray Example:** (Not working)

```
let jsonSchemaResult = "{\r\n  \"namespace\": \"x\",\r\n  \"doc\": \"1\",\r\n  \"type\": \"record\",\r\n  \"name\": \"event\",\r\n  \"fields\": [\r\n    {\"name\": \"event_httppageload\",  \"type\": [\"null\", {\r\n    \"type\": \"array\",\r\n      \"items\": {\r\n         \"type\": \"record\",\r\n         \"name\": \"EventHttppageloadRecord\",\r\n         \"fields\": [\r\n            {\"name\": \"url\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"]},\r\n            {\"name\": \"setup_time\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"int\"]},\r\n            {\"name\": \"duration\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"int\"]},\r\n            {\"name\": \"data_downloaded\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"int\"]},\r\n            {\"name\": \"is_error\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"boolean\"]},\r\n            {\"name\": \"error_code\", \"type\": [\"null\", {\"type\": \"enum\", \"name\": \"HttpErrorCodeEnum\", \"symbols\" : [\"NO_ERROR\", \"FILE_NOT_FOUND\", \"NETWORK_ERROR\", \"NETWORK_TIMEOUT\",\"INTERNAL_ERROR\"]}]}\r\n         ]\r\n      }\r\n    }]}]}"

let schema = Schema(jsonSchemaResult)
let avroValue: AvroValue
//Please ignore the variable "result", it is never used
avroValue = result.toAvro()
let encodedBytes = avroValue.encode(schema!)

extension ResultObject : AvroValueConvertible {
    public func toAvro() -> AvroValue {

       let object1: DCUrlResult = DCUrlResult.init(url: "url", label: "label", loadTime: 111, 
       pingTime: 222, pageSize: 333, error: true)
       var randomarray: Array<DCUrlResult> = Array<DCUrlResult>.init()
       randomarray.append(object1)

       let returnThinkk = AvroValue.avroRecordValue([
                "event_httppageload" : avroNullableArrayValue(v: randomarray, converter:{
                    $0?.map({avroNullableRecordValue(v: $0, converter: {
                           let newAvro = AvroValue.avroRecordValue([
                          "url" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                          "setup_time" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                          "duration" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                          "data_downloaded" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                          "is_error" : $0.url.toAvroString(),
                          "error_code" : $0.url.toAvroString()
                            ])
                            return newAvro
                        })})
                    })
                ])
            }
        }

public func avroNullableArrayValue<T>(v: [T]?, converter: ([T]?) -> [AvroValue]?) -> AvroValue {
         if(v == nil) {
             //return avroNilValue()
             let box = Box(AvroValue.avroNullValue)
             return .avroUnionValue(0, box)
         } else {
             let pend2 = converter(v!)!
             let box = Box(AvroValue.avroArrayValue(pend2))
             return .avroUnionValue(1, box)
         }
     }

extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
     public func toAvroString() -> AvroValue {
         switch self {
         case .none:
             let box = Box(AvroValue.avroNullValue)
             return .avroUnionValue(0, box)
         case .some(let v):
             let box = Box(v.toAvro())
             return .avroUnionValue(1, box)
         }
     }
 }
extension Optional where Wrapped == Int32 {
    public func toAvro() -> AvroValue {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            let box = Box(AvroValue.avroNullValue)
            return .avroUnionValue(0, box)
        case .some(let v):
            let box = Box(v.toAvro())
            return .avroUnionValue(1, box)
        }
    }
}
extension Optional where Wrapped == Bool {
    public func toAvro() -> AvroValue {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            let box = Box(AvroValue.avroNullValue)
            return .avroUnionValue(0, box)
        case .some(let v):
            let box = Box(v.toAvro())
            return .avroUnionValue(1, box)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the schema for the AvroRecord:

```
{
  "namespace": "x",
  "doc": "1",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "event",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "event_httppageload",  "type": ["null", {
       "type": "record",
       "name": "EventHttppageloadRecord",
       "fields": [
          {"name": "url", "type": ["null", "string"]},
          {"name": "setup_time", "type": ["null", "int"]},
          {"name": "duration", "type": ["null", "int"]},
          {"name": "data_downloaded", "type": ["null", "int"]},
          {"name": "is_error", "type": ["null", "boolean"]},
          {"name": "error_code", "type": ["null", "string"]}
       ]

    }]}]}
```

This is the schema for the AvroArray containing AvroRecords:

```
{
  "namespace": "x",
  "doc": "1",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "event",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "event_httppageload",  "type": ["null", {
    "type": "array",
      "items": {
         "type": "record",
         "name": "EventHttppageloadRecord",
         "fields": [
            {"name": "url", "type": ["null", "string"]},
            {"name": "setup_time", "type": ["null", "int"]},
            {"name": "duration", "type": ["null", "int"]},
            {"name": "data_downloaded", "type": ["null", "int"]},
            {"name": "is_error", "type": ["null", "boolean"]},
            {"name": "error_code", "type": ["null", "string"]}
         ]
      }
    }]}]}
```

The library that I'm using for this is [BlueSteel for Swift](https://github.com/saksdirect/BlueSteel) which is theoretically based on [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/).

*Please, feel free to ask for more code in the case you need it to figure out what could be going wrong.*